# ocamlbuild include extra packages

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am working through the [LLVM ocaml tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/OCamlLangImpl1.html), and using the following command line to compile:

```
ocamlbuild -cflags -g,-I,+llvm-3.4 -lflags -I,+llvm-3.4 toy.byte
```

Is there any way to move those extra cflags and lflags into the _tags or myocamlbuild.ml files so that I don't need to type them/can store them in source control/make reproducible builds?

Here is the _tags file:

```
<{lexer,parser}.ml>: use_camlp4, pp(camlp4of)
<*.{byte,native}>: g++, use_llvm, use_llvm_analysis
<*.{byte,native}>: use_llvm_executionengine, use_llvm_target
<*.{byte,native}>: use_llvm_scalar_opts, use_bindings
```

And here is the myocamlbuild.ml file:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin;;

ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm";;
ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm_analysis";;
ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm_executionengine";;
ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm_target";;
ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm_scalar_opts";;

flag ["link"; "ocaml"; "g++"] (S[A"-cc"; A"g++ -rdynamic"]);;
dep ["link"; "ocaml"; "use_bindings"] ["bindings.o"];;
```

Comment: Take a look at other 'myocamlbuild.ml' files on github and other places. This --and your other question-- are pretty easy to determine from those samples.

Comment: You must have a different definition of "easy to determine" than I.

Answer (score 2):

I do something like...

```
let mlflags = []
and cflags = []
and clibs = []

let rec arg_weave p = function
  | x::xs -> (A p) :: (A x) :: arg_weave p xs
  | []    -> []
and arg x = A x
...
let () = dispatch begin function
  | After_rules ->
    flag ["ocaml"; "compile"] (S (List.map arg mlflags));
    flag ["c"; "compile"]     (S (arg_weave "-ccopt" cflags));
    flag ["c"; "link"]        (S (arg_weave "-cclib" clibs));
    ...
  end
```

The other option is to tag additional options. For example, in the ocaml_specific.ml file they have one set-up for debug and all the combinations of flag options for where the option is relevant.

```
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "compile"; "byte"] (A "-g");;
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "link"; "byte"; "program"] (A "-g");;
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "pack"; "byte"] (A "-g");;
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "compile"; "native"] (A "-g");;
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "link"; "native"; "program"] (A "-g");;
flag ["ocaml"; "debug"; "pack"; "native"] (A "-g");;
```

then, in the `_tags` file, you can have `true : debug` to turn it on for all files, or `true` can be replaced by a pattern for limiting the option. So if an option doesn't exist already, you can create your own and you'll see that it's similar to the fully myocamlbuild.ml solution, but additional flags for each tag instead of including them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

`-g` is replaced by `true: debug` in `_tags`.

`-I` options ideally should be replaced by the corresponding ocamlfind package, e.g. calling `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind` and specifying `true: package(llvm,llvm_analysis)` in `_tags` and/or whatever other packages are called (and remove `ocaml_lib` calls in `myocamlbuild.ml`).

On the side note, just create a `Makefile` with whatever `ocamlbuild` invocation is needed and run `make` to build.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand the first two parts of your answer.  Could you give an example of what you're talking about re: -use-ocamlfind?

Comment: The makefile trick is what I have in place now.  It just seemed silly.

Comment: In the _tags file, you can have lines `true : debug`, `true : dtypes`, `true : profile`, `true : rectypes`, `true: bin_annot`, `true:output_obj`, ... to turn on those specific options. You can also replace `true` with patterns for specific files. These are built-in flags in the `ocaml/ocamlbuild/ocaml_specific.ml` file.